# What are the privileges which only moderators have?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I've been reading up on Stack Exchange's moderation policies to learn about creating a good online community. And I came across this:

> Moderators are human exception handlers, there to deal with those
>   (hopefully rare) exceptional conditions that should not normally
>   happen, but when they do, they can bring your entire community to a
>   screaming halt — if you don’t have human exception handling in place.

So, I was wondering given the strength of the reputation based moderation abilities, what are some of the edge cases that only moderators can handle?

Comment: Mods can nuke users who are posting spam, suspend users who create trouble for others, delete and undelete almost everything, see more information. None of these things can be done by high-rep users.

Comment: Mods also have the honor(?) of jousting with users who object to their actions in meta, at least until it becomes an all-out brawl.

Answer (score 6):

Most regular community moderation tools focus on content, which is relatively easy to moderate. We mainly deal with the problems that users face, as well as the problem users. Such as

- breaking up fights,
- curtailing vandalism,
- dealing with unscrupulous users cheating through voting across multiple accounts or through stealing content,
- nuking troll accounts and spammers,

to name a few.

We do get involved a fair bit in cleaning up junk, particularly the kind that's left by the most persistent of trolls and spammers, but the *vast majority* of low-quality content is swiftly dealt with by reviewers and high-rep users before it ever reaches us.

A more in-depth answer with a list of mod-only privileges and abilities can be found here: [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role)

Comment: Nuking terrible content; enforcing the 'be nice' policy; [trying to] nip problems in the bud.

Comment: How do the mods' relate to the high-rep (I'm talking in the 15-20k range) users' actions. Do the mods see/ get alerted to (some?) of their actions? Could one conceptualize it as a police/ court relationship? Or are each group totally independent of each other? And if so how do you know when one there's a fight, for example? Is it passively waiting for a user to report abuse?

Comment: I was hoping some would post an actual list of exceptions. ;P Like VotingFraudException, PlagiarismException, AbusiveBehaviorException, VandalismException, etc, etc. BE FUN! Uh oh, FunException. Can't have that.

Comment: @MCB: We're really just 15k-20k users with a few extra privileges and are elected by the community. We have immediate access to a list of flags that are raised by the community, so yes it's pretty much just passively waiting. (There's not a whole lot of actual *waiting* though...)

Comment: @animuson: An exception has occurred. Class: MissedOpportunityException Site: MetaStackOverflow PostId: 280135 Abort, Retry, Fail?

Comment: Ok, but then why have the mods? ... I see it's partially addressed in your edited comment. If it's just that why not just have a those powers given based on rep but require group voting to ensure fairness/ moderate the effect of individual mood? What's official moderation bringing to the table that goes above and beyond people passionate about the site who have put in the time and effort to understand it?

Comment: @MCB: Mods have access to a great deal of behind-the-scenes information, which includes sensitive data such as user email addresses (subject to the privacy policy of course). This is something that ideally only a very small set of people should be able to access. The group voting part is already handled through mod elections.

Comment: So it's a security issue then? There are actions which require access to personal information to keep the site running, which would be inappropriate to tie to comment rep, and the election process is that guarantor of the ethics? Does that sum it up?

Comment: They sign a moderator contract which is taken very seriously and moderators have stepped down in the past when the contract has been broken @MCB. Shog once explained it to me in great detail, I will try to find the link of that discussion for you.

Answer (score 4):

- They have access to all the abilities of 20k users regardless of their reputation.
- Their votes are binding. Any place we have voting — close, open, delete, undelete, offensive, migration, etc — that vote will reach the threshold and take effect immediately if a single diamond moderator casts a vote.
- They can lock posts. Locked posts cannot be voted on, commented, or changed in any way.
- They can see more data in the system, including vote statistics (but not 'who voted for this post') and user profile information.
- They can view all deleted posts on an individual user's profile.
- They can place users in timed suspension, and delete users if necessary.
- They can perform large-scale maintenance actions such as merging questions and tags, tag synonym approvals, unbounded question migration, and so forth.
- They can convert a post into Community Wiki status, or convert an answer into a comment.
- They can (at their discretion) refund and cancel a bounty.
- They are not subject to the flag, close vote, delete vote, review count, etc. limits.

*[[source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75192/262755)]*

Comment: Nearly unbounded question migration. I think there is a 60 day statute of limitation...